# Scheduling of jobs through SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, azure, azure-data-factory

I have to write a stored procedures for scheduling the Azure pipelines (Jobs).

- Frequency ----Number of times batch needs to run in a day
- Timing column will have entry for batch start time

Table A will have static entries for batches. Frequency denotes in a day how many times job will run and timing column will have the batch run time separated by comma(,)

```
Batch_ID   Batch_Name  Frequency    Timing 
-----------------------------------------------
1          ABC           2          7:00,13:00
```

Table B will have listing of jobs corresponding to one particular batch.This table will be static and have one time entry like table B.

Table B

```
Batch_ID   JOB_ID       JOB_NM
--------------------------------
1            1           Job_1
1            2           Job_1
```

Table C will contain the dependencies of the jobs in a batch

Table C

```
Batch_ID    JOB_ID      DEPENDENY_JOB_ID
----------------------------------------
1             1
1             2              1
```

When Batch executes, table D will be populated with batch start time.

Table D

```
Batch_ID   Batch_Name   Status    start_Time   end_time
-------------------------------------------------------
1             abc       Start     7:00
```

As soon as Table E is populated,table D will populated with Job details.Job 2 will start only when job 1 finishes.

Table E

```
Batch_ID   Batch_Name  JOB_ID    JOB_NM      Start_Time     End_Time
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            abc         1        Job_1       7:00
1            abc         2        Job_2       7:15
```

When Job 2 completes then we will update the Table D end time column.

Once first run is completed, we need to check frequency column of table A and run the job again (if it's more than 1) and do the entire exercise again.

In case our 1st batch didn't complete before the start time of batch 2 then we have to hold the 2nd batch until batch 1 is completed.

Could anyone help me how to start this?

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want/need to do, so please feel free to implement it. Good luck! If you get stuck, then please do let us know and ask a question about it. *(Side note, I recommend against storing delimited data, so when you do implement this I suggest changing that to a normalised data structure.)*

Comment: What's your question boss?

Comment: I know how you start . . . `create procedure`.  If your intent is that someone write all this code for you, your question is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff said, you are lacking a question on your "question".

If I can give an opinion on this, I dont think its a good design idea to split your logic between data factory and stored procedures in a database. Be mindful that in the future, the user mantaining the pipelines may not have access to the database and will not be able to understand half of it. Even if YOU are the one mantaining this, 2 years from now chances are you are going to forget what you did and following the line between 2 resources may take you more time than it should. It will also make troubleshooting harder.

It really depends on the scenario you are working on, but to sum it up: try to have everything logic related in one place.

Hope this helped!